# No boot option after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, wubi

I just installed Ubuntu on my Windows Vista laptop using the Windows Installer. After the install I rebooted the system and Ubuntu started automatically. When I restarted again I did not get the option of choosing OS and directly went to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try >>

1) Restart the PC

2) Press F8 (continuously)

3) You will get a GRUB (drive's boot menu), You will see the Ubuntu option. ENTER it.
and YOUR DONE!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Computer, Properties, Advanced system settings, Startup& recovery settings, Time to display operating systems: Set it to 10.

[image: System properties]

[image: Advanced system settings]

[image: Startup & Recovery settings]