# No grub menu after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from USB from inside Windows. When I restarted the PC there was no grub menu. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is also happened to me you can take a look on
[Can I install Ubuntu inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows)

you can try this where d is your iso image drive and run this command

```
D:\wubi.exe --force-wubi
```

Comment: i will try this

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing the file below when you installed Ubuntu.

```
/boot/grub/core.img
```

So you need to use `chroot` to have it fixed. [Take a look at this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you said was that you used a Wubi installer and afterwards you are unable to select Ubuntu as your operating system.

The answer has been provided here:
[No boot option after Ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131827/no-boot-option-after-ubuntu-install)