# No ubuntu option at Boot screen

Tags: boot

Installed ubuntu using the windows installer, rebooted when it was finished and did not get the option to select it at the boot screen. Dell Latitude D630 Win XP.

Comment: check out this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131827/no-boot-option-after-ubuntu-install?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

simples you need to add an entry to the boot.ini i suggest you use easybcd as it is free

Comment: Can you add more instructions explaining how to do that?