# Can't Access GRUB2 after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: boot, grub2

I had a Slackware Linux installed with LILO Boot Loader and I decided to change to Ubuntu so I deleted Slackware Partition and used EasyBCD to return to Windows 7 Loader
then I burned Ubuntu 12.10 64bit onto a DVD and booted it up.

The installation and everything else is fine but when I Reboot it boots straight up to Windows 7 not even to GRUB2 Menu just windows 7.

Any Help?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/131849/62483) could work for you. It is for Windows Vista but maybe is the same with Seven.

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed Using Boot-Repair tool
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
With Recommended Repair

Answer (score 0):

It booted directly to Windows loader probably because you installed the Grub2 bootloader to the Ubuntu partition (sdan), instead of the disk's MBR (sda).

The latest version of Easy BCD has an option to add your Grub/Grub2 list to the Windows boot menu options. Try it.